# App not compliant and removed :Security Vulnerabilities : Insecure Hostname Verification

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-security

My App has been removed with following message

**We found that your app contains security vulnerabilities, which can expose user information or damage a user’s device. This is a violation of Device and Network Abuse policy. Specifically, your app(s) are vulnerable to Insecure Hostname Verification. To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article.**

I am using Google's Volley library to establish the connection. This message points me to to implement verify method in HostNameVerifier to adhere to policies. But, I do not use HostNameVerifier nor do I find it anywhere in the source code.

When queried further the google support sent me the following

**your app is currently using the following vulnerable implementation of HostnameVerifier.
Lg/a/a/a/a/l/e$a;
Lg/a/a/a/a/l/f$a;**

I do not understand these character sequences that they are pointing to.

If anyone has any help to solve this issue it is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> our app is currently using the following vulnerable implementation of HostnameVerifier. Lg/a/a/a/a/l/e$a; Lg/a/a/a/a/l/f$a;
>
> I do not understand these character sequences that they are pointing to.

`L` means it's a class type, and `g/a/a/a/a/l/e$a` is an obfuscated class name where `$a` is an inner class. Have a look at `mapping.txt` in your release `build` outputs to decode back to the original class name.

Even if you don't have a `HostnameVerifier` in your code, there can be libraries you are using with an bad implementation of `HostnameVerifier`.

Comment: Very helpful Answer Thanks.